# Pysimplegui and table row color

Tags: colors, row, pysimplegui

I'm using latest pysimplegui with latest python.
I have this table where the first 4 rows have colors.
Is it possible to make certain cells(background color) in a row to not get the color assigned to that row?

So i'm not talking about

> alternating_row_color='color'

, but this

> window['-table-'].Update(row_colors=[[0,'red']])
>
> window['-table-'].Update(row_colors=[[1,'yellow']])
>
> window['-table-'].Update(row_colors=[[2,'green']])
>
> window['-table-'].Update(row_colors=[[3,'green']])

This makes the entire row in a color, but there are certain cells i don't want to have a color assigned to it.

Thanks

Comment: Basically, only one color for one row. The answer is No for the question is if it is possible to get different color for different cell. Simulation of Table by using matrix of elements, like 'sg.Text`. will work, but need more management on it.